# pygtk/gtk python window like android toast

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I would like to make android toast like window in python. I made this window but I have no idea how to make it looks like "android toast" (nicely designed)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygtk, threading, gobject
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk 
import time

class kontrolor:
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.threads_enter()
        self.okno = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
        self.clicked()#self.wins(0, None)

    def run(self):
        gobject.idle_add(self.wins(0,None))

    def clicked(self):
        self.wins(0,None)    

    def wins(self,w,data):      
        self.windowko = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.windowko.set_default_size(440, 605)
        self.windowko.show_all() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = kontrolor()
        gtk.main()
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What OS are you using? On Linux you can get desktop-native notifications using the [libnotify](https://developer.gnome.org/libnotify/) API (not sure what the Python bindings are, sorry).

Comment: I am using Linux, I need to show several notifications (not just to hide it after few seconds) but I need to be able now long they shoudl be visible or change information inside this notification. (for example show timer/counter when each second will increase value - 1, 2, 3, 4 seconds...)

Comment: (And ideally to show 2 - 3 notifications at once with ability to set location on the screen)

Comment: Better to use the OS facility for notifications than to roll your own. Your non-native notifications won't integrate with other native notifications from other apps, confusing your users.

Comment: If you really do want to roll your own, you can create a standard GtkWindow without decorations (to remove the border and titlebar) and use some sort of window manager toolkit to place that window on a "good" position in the screen. I don't know of any for Python. Good luck!